# Index out of bounds exception in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I am getting the below error for the attached code. The issue here is that the thread is running even after exiting the "for" loop. All i am doing is that at the click of a button, i am uploading a bunch of files to cloud. `ListofDocs[]` is where i have stored my list of files that I want to upload. Any help is appreciated. TIA.

```
11-03 21:23:27.793: E/AndroidRuntime(24480): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11897
11-03 21:23:27.793: E/AndroidRuntime(24480): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=12
11-03 21:23:27.793: E/AndroidRuntime(24480):    at com.projects.scloud.PicsList$1$1.run(PicsList.java:99)
11-03 21:23:27.793: E/AndroidRuntime(24480):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

```
for(i=0; i < ListofDocs.length; i++) {
          Log.i("Value of i: ", String.valueOf(i));
        MessageText.setText("Upload Documents");

        /************* Php script path ****************/
        upLoadServerUri = "http://www.androidexample.com/media/UploadToServer.php";
        Backup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(DocsList.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                MessageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                            }
                        });                   

                        uploadFile(ListofDocs[i]);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
      }
```

Comment: A thread will run until it's completed or cancelled. It's a separate object.  Why are you expecting the threads to complete before the for loop finishes?  That said, your code is completely wrong.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: you are many times setting different dynamic onclicnlistener to one widget (Button?). This does not make sense to me. You'll be able just to upload last file in the list if your code worked.

Comment: If you're doing a fire-and-forget upload (as it appears you're doing) you should use a Service so that you're not tied to the Activity needing to be present while the file uploads

Comment: uploadFile() is a method with string argument that uploads file one by one and that's why it is in the for loop. I want to execute the thread in the loop to make sure that the files uploaded in the cloud storage properly.

Comment: This is not a thread-safety problem.  You are likely to get the same exception if all reading / writing of `i` is thread-safe.  Rather, it is just a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the looping from outside the thread to inside the thread. Since the Thread executes only once, my code was getting executed only once and was incrementing the array element. The code now is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the code to compile, `i` must be an instance variable, not a local variable.  That means that `ListofDocs[i]` will refer to the value of that instance variable ... at the point in time that the thread body actually executes.  But the chances are that that will be *after* the outer loop has incremented `i` to `ListofDocs.length`.  Hence the array index is out of bounds.

You should not use an instance variable.  Rather, you should use a `final` local variable; e.g.

```
for(int i=0; i < ListofDocs.length; i++) {
    final int final_i = i;
    ...
        // in the anonymous inner class
        uploadFile(ListofDocs[final_i]);
}
```

Comment: I have changed the looping from outside the thread to inside the thread. Since the Thread executes only once, my code was getting executed only once and was incrementing the array element. The code now is working fine. Thanks to all.

Comment: @user2945300 - You didn't need to fix it that way.  However, it is likely that it was the *right* way.  Spawning a whole bunch of threads to upload files in parallel is not a good idea.